# Custom ordering in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to implement custom ordering for my table. For example I have a table called "TestTest" with values: `a, d01, d04, d02, b` . I need to select data and order them so that values with "d" will be first and rest will be sorted alphanumerical. So the result would be `d01,d02,d03,a,b`

Script to create and insert data:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTest(
Name varchar(200)
)
DELETE FROM TestTest

INSERT INTO TestTest( Name )
VALUES( 'a' )

INSERT INTO TestTest( Name )
VALUES( 'd01');

INSERT INTO TestTest( Name )
VALUES( 'd04');

INSERT INTO TestTest( Name )
VALUES( 'd02');

INSERT INTO TestTest( Name )
VALUES( 'b' );
```

Thx for any help ;)

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789241/tsql-is-it-possible-to-define-the-sort-order might be a starting point for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select *
From TestTest
Order By CASE WHEN LEFT(Name,1)='d' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,Name
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef9e7/1)

Answer (score 1):

Quick soution:

```
Select * 
from TestTest
order by case when Name like 'd%' then 'aaaaa'+Name else Name end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from TestTest order by case when Name='d01' then 1
                                            when Name='d02' then 2
                                            when Name ='d04' then 3
                                            end  desc
```

Comment: This will give a random soultion for the 'a' and 'b'