# How to sort part of the table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with column "ActionDate" that has 2 types of dates:

- some different real dates and
- constant values '1980-01-01'

I need to sort data in such a way that real dates should come first in ascending order and constant values should come after.

The data sample:

1) The current state:

```
ActionDate

2014-01-03
2014-01-01
2014-01-02
1980-01-01
2014-01-04
2014-01-05
1980-01-01
```

2) The desired state:

```
ActionDate

2014-01-01
2014-01-02
2014-01-03
2014-01-04
2014-01-05
1980-01-01
1980-01-01
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [TSQL - Is it possible to define the sort order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789241/tsql-is-it-possible-to-define-the-sort-order)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement to create an order

```
SELECT ActionDate
FROM [Your_Table]
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ActionDate = '01-01-1980' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, ActionDate
```

The `CASE` statement checks the date, when it is your reference date it assigns the value 1. When used in the `OREDER BY` it means rows marked 0 will be before those marked 1.

The second part of the `ORDER BY` uses the natural date ordering to sort them from oldest to newest.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c69e/4) which includes the sort order field to help you see what is happening.

Comment: What does 1 and 0 means?

Comment: @tesicg - Answer updated, I'd missed the keyword `WHEN` and I've added more info to answer your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * , 'OrderDate' = CASE ActionDate 
WHEN '01-01-1980' THEN 2
ELSE 1
END 
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY OrderDate, data
```

In my solution, I created a column OrderDate which has values 1 or 2 , 1 for all the real datas and 2 for  '01-01-1980' then you can sort them after that column and after the data column.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this would probably do it:

```
SELECT ActionDate
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE ActionDate <> '01/01/1980'
ORDER BY ActionDate

UNION ALL 

SELECT ActionDate
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE ActionDate = '01/01/1980'
```

Comment: You can't have an `ORDER BY` preceding a UNION statement, and besides, why use `UNION` when you can do everything in a single select with `CASE`?

Answer (score -1):

Since 1980-01-01 is the timestamp start value, I suppose that your date is generated automatically to store the 'today date' when the action occur, in other words, there is no date lower than 1980-01-01 and in this case, a simple order by can do the task (and it's much more faster)

```
SELECT ActionDate
FROM [Your_Table]
ORDER BY ActionDate DESC
```

Comment: Wrong -- look at their desired output.  They want all non-1980 dates in ascending order, then 1908 dates at the bottom.  Besides, this was already answered and accepted.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry, I hadn't notice the "ascending" order