# How to manually sort an order defined by the user

Tags: mysql, objective-c, sorting

Okay, not looking to sort a table that I, the programmer, define like in [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789241/tsql-is-it-possible-to-define-the-sort-order). I want to sort in the order defined by the user. Take this situation:

User adds to the table, names, in this order; third, first, second, and fourth. So the table looks like this:

```
1: third
2: first
3: second
4: fourth
```

Now the user doesn't want to see this table in the order it was inserted into the table, nor in alphabetical order by the text, but in the order that best fits the user:

```
first
second
third
fourth
```

How shall I accomplish this? What I am working with is creating an objective-c app that imports the sqlite3.lib file into the project. Therefore I use methods like sqlite3_open( .. ) etc.

Let me know if this isn't a sufficient amount of information :)

Answer (score 0):

Just assign an ID to each item the user adds. So if the user adds:

```
1: third
2: first
3: second
4: fourth
```

assign ID's to each item:

```
1: third  (id = 0)
2: first  (id = 1)
3: second (id = 2)
4: fourth (id = 3)
```

so when a user wants to reorder the list, let them drag and drop each item to the location they desire. When they're done editing, just update the id field for each item like so:

```
2: first  (id = 0)
3: second (id = 1)
1: third  (id = 2)
4: fourth (id = 3)
```

So now when you have to reload the data from the database, you simply sort the the id you've assigned, it'll always be in the order the user desires.

Comment: I like that, this would work but say I called id index, bc id is already used as 1: third, id of 1, wouldn't I have to increment/decrement all rows below the destination row? That could lead up to changing thousands of rows of the user moved the last row to the very top

Comment: Are you expecting that much user input?

Comment: Perhaps no, but in further uses of this method yeah

Comment: If using this method becomes inexpensive then I'd use it :)

Comment: Btw, I noticed you're developing this with Objective-C, is there any reason you aren't using Core Data? With Core Data you could use the method I described, and just have it return the data to you in a sorted array whenever you load it. I do that in one of my apps and have noticed noticed the slightest delay. Just a thought, hope it helps.

Comment: I guess I never looked into core data, yet. Reasons of using sql is bc I have a table of timers then I have a table of date stamps for each timer, therefore there'll be a lot of date stamps for each timer. But when I do work from sql to objective-c I manage the data to give me the appropriate arrays

Comment: Oh ok. You may be surprised, it might be a lot more simple using Core Data. You can set up a simple "one to many" relationship with the date stamps and timers. It might be worth checking out for not only this, but future objective c projects.

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciate the tip, I'll definitely try out this method with what I got now :)