# TSQL - How to return rows with a specific value last?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question is reverse of this question.

[TSQL - Is it possible to define the sort order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789241/tsql-is-it-possible-to-define-the-sort-order)

I want to return some records from SQL Server database, sorted in ascending order based on a column's value BUT two particular records should always be on the end.

The original SQL (which needs to be changed) is below:

```
select code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription
from codes
where code_id > '000001' and code_id < '000100'
order by CategoryDescription
```

The results are returned as

- 000003   ***First Record
- 000002   ***Another Record
- 000004   Apple
- 000016   Books
- 000014   Cables

I want the below result (first two with asteriks on the last):

- 000004   Apple
- 000016   Books
- 000014   Cables
- 000003   ***First Record
- 000002   ***Another Record

I tried the below UNION statement but the resultset is automatically sorted in ascending order and those two rows are in the beginning by default.

```
select code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription
from codes
where code_id > '000003' and code_id < '000100' 
--order by categoryDescription

UNION

select code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription
from codes
where code_id > '000001' and code_id < '000004'
```

Comment: please show some sample data and expected output

Comment: First in the ORDER BY, use a CASE expression to put the two particular values last. Then order by the column.

Comment: can you provide a sample table and the result you require out of it.

Comment: @jarlh i know how to put some values in first forcefully, in ORDER BY, but never saw the code to put some values in the last. can you tell.

Comment: @Dheeraj Sharma provided

Comment: @TheGameiswar provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to maintain the union then you could do something like this:

```
select * from (
    select 'T' as Success,  code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription, 1 as order
    from codes
    where code_id > '000003' and code_id < '000100' 

    UNION

    select 'T' as Success,  code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription, 2 as order
    from codes
    where code_id > '000001' and code_id < '000004'
) x
order by x.order
```

Comment: You have to append ", CategoryDescription" at the very end to make it perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'T' as Success,  code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription
from codes
where (code_id > '000003' and code_id < '000100') or (code_id > '000001' and code_id < '000004')
```

order by code_id  desc

your code is too long why dont you change it to this?

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for this

```
select 'T' as Success,  code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription
from codes
where (code_id > '000003' and code_id < '000100') OR 
      (code_id > '000001' and code_id < '000004') 
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN (code_id > '000003' and code_id < '000100') THEN 1
           WHEN (code_id > '000001' and code_id < '000004') THEN 2
         END
```